# window.setStatusBarColor doesn't work?

Tags: android, colors, styles, themes

In onCreate I do this:

```
    this.setTheme(getTheme());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS , WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS );

        w.setStatusBarColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

What I want to achieve is after applying my usual theme I want to set the Status bar green. But that doesn't happen. The line is executed, but the color doesn't change. Anything I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the flags. I use this code

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary_dark));
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned it, but I need the bar to be transparent.

Comment: do you want it transparent or you want it green?